# Why JPanel repaint only once?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create window where after 3 seconds image automatically  will change.
This is my code:

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
pan pane= new pan();
frame.add(pane);
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
frame.setVisible(true);



    try{
        for(int i=0;i<returnedArray.size();i++){                
            pane.img=returnedArray.get(i).getFrontImage();
            Thread.sleep(3000);     
            pane.repaint();
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


class pan extends JPanel{
    public Image img; 

     public void paint(Graphics g) {
          g.drawImage( img, 0, 0, null);
     }
}
```

...but I see last image all the time  :(

I think that maybe JVM is improving my code?

How can I avoid this?
Maybe I am doing it wrong?

I will be very gratefull for any clue :)

Comment: You're blocking the GUI thread. Use a swing timer instead of `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Can you show us code that compiles?

Comment: Override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, not the `paint(Graphics)` method. Also, call `super.paintComponent(g)` in the method.

Comment: Thank you all for replies!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your problem be this line in your for loop:

```
pane.img=returnedArray.get(2).getFrontImage();
```

which always selects the same image?  Aside from this, you should probably use a Timer as pointed out in comments instead of using Thread.sleep

Comment: Timer solves problem. Number "2" is my mistake when I format code on this page :) I will correct it in my post. Thank You!